# How do i get Combobox item count?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox, itemlistener

i have 2 combobox combobox1(fogcomb)
 is fill with movie title and i want to if i choose the 2nd item in fogcomb then `int asd` variable get 2 value and if i choose 4th item then value=4

```
fogcomb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            asd=fogcomb.getSelectedIndex();

            if (e.getItem().equals(tesztvalt)) {
    try {
      String sql="SELECT Idő,Terem FROM Idopontok I,Filmlista F WHERE Cím like'"+tesztvalt+"'and I.FKód=F.FKód and I.FKód='"+asd+"'"; 
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String name=rs.getString("Idő");
                        String name2=rs.getString("Terem");
                        String name3="   ";
                        fogcomb2.addItem(name+name3+name2);             
                    }

                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

Comment: And the question is why it returns 1 when use select second item and why it returns 3 when you select fourth item and how to add 1 to the returned value?

Comment: asd=fogcomb.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the indexes are `0` based you should use :

```
asd=fogcomb.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
```

**EDIT**

You are adding itemlistener to wrong combobox

```
fogcomb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
```

should be replaced by:

```
fogcomb.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
```

Comment: did you try to print value of `asd` ?

Comment: I am not getting you. On selecting an item in `fogcombo2` you are adding more items to same `fogcombo2`

Comment: true, now work, one more question, now when i choose an item in combo1 its add item for combo2 BUT i want to overwrite the items in combo2 when i select a new item in combo1

Comment: You need to remove all items from `combo2` by using `removeAllItems()` before adding new items.

Comment: Your Welcome. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply by:

```
 int size = jComboBox.getItemCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the corresponding index position of a selection in a `JComboBox` you can call `getSelectedIndex()` once the focus is lost on the `JComboBox`. Note that `getSelectedIndex()` returns a value starting at 0. Therefore, you may want to add +1 to the returned value if you want the first selection to return a value of 1, the second selection to return a value of 2, etc.